# Simplest way to transfer photos from PC to iPad (not sync-all)?

Tags: ipad, photos

I'd like to transfer selected photos from my PC to an iPad Air 2 running iOS 9.2. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99343/the-simplest-way-to-transfer-photos-from-an-iphone-to-pc-selectively-not-sync-a) thread shows how to transfer from iPad to PC (Use Windows Explorer and treat iPad as a camera), and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152394/how-to-transfer-one-photo-from-pc-to-iphone-6) thread suggests using Dropbox.

Can I use Windows Explorer and have the photos show up in the camera roll on my iPad? If not, what's the easiest way of doing so without syncing?

**Note**: I can see and copy JPGs from the iPad to my PC with Windows Explorer. I am not able to copy from my PC to the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get photos from a PC to an iOS device would be backing up certain photos to a cloud service like Google Photos or Dropbox. There is no way to get photos from PC into the iOS Camera Roll that I am aware of. Check out Google Photos. It would be the most seamless solution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it in a while, but [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) should do what you what.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well you can use [iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204283) to transter photos from **and** to your iPad within the **PC File Explorer**.

Once installed there is a new **iCloud Photos** folder in your explorer that contains 3 sub-folders:

- one for upload
- one for download
- last one for your shared photos (this is an iCloud feature)

Hope it still exists and that it will work.